# German national visa - category d, can spouse work?

Tags: working-visas, germany

I am currently a non-EU citizen. I have an offer from a company for work. The company stated that I will have to apply for a German national category-d visa.

If I am a holder of German national category d visa (employment visa), then:

Can my spouse who is also highly skilled worker in Germany without any restrictions?

Comment: You're asking three questions; it's better to post them separately.  I think the answer to your first question is "Yes"  and I could probably find a reference to back that up, but I don't know the answer to the two questions you ask in number (2).

Comment: The site does not allow me to post a question for 40 mins after I post a question. Can you please post the source for question 1

Comment: Done, I have posted a different question

Comment: If you hold a degree that is relevant to the position, and you are over a certain yearly salary you can apply for a §19a _Blaue Karte EU_, which is easier to obtain and grants more freedom than the regular work visa. It includes that your spouse and children up to 18y are allowed to work automatically regardless of their level of education. I don't have time to post a full answer though, and probably there are some already.

Answer (score 1):

The German national category D visa is more or less given to you to enter Germany and apply for the residence permit. Then it depends on which residence permit you will get.

Also, for your spouse to work in Germany, he/she should get first a visa, and then the residence permit and work permit. Usually, in such cases, he/she can apply for the visa and later for residence permit for the purpose of the family re-union. However, he/she can also apply for the other types of visa / residence permit (e.g., for the working purposes).

In case if he/she gets the residence permit for the purpose of the family re-union, and if you will have the residence permit for the purpose of employment or Blue Card EU, your spouse should get the same work permit as you (e.g., if the enterpreneurship is allowed/prohiited for you, the same could be for your spouse).