# Can a person travel on the dependent visa and work?

Tags: working-visas, germany, indian-citizens, dependent-visa

I am getting an employment visa (long term) for Germany. My wife will be traveling with me as dependent on "Family reunion" visa. Both of us will be getting eAT (Electronic residence permit) once we land in Germany.

Now, is it possible for my spouse to get a job and work?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Are both Indian? What visa are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I answered [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/12064/13223) and [here](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11515/13223), she will get the job permission with a very high probability. Actually, her visa can allow her to work even before she will get the residence permit.

One remark: You won't get the eAT automatically after landing, you need to apply for it.